# what is "cavity mode width"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

to my knowledge a cavity mode is a standing wave with nodes at either edge of its cavity. (standing light wave) each has a frequency and a wavelength and the first 1 is just half a wavelength etc...

I read in a paper called Strong coupling phenomena in quantum microcavity structures that

> "For ω<sub>c</sub> =/= ω<sub>s</sub>, as may arise from imperfectly controlled growth, the
>   observed Fabry–P´erot frequency is no longer equal to ωc, and is in
>   fact more sensitive to ωs than to ωc, since LDBR is signiﬁcantly
>   greater than Lc. Because of the fact that the mirrors have ﬁnite
>   transmission probability, the cavity mode has ﬁnite width
>   Δc (full
>   width at halfmaximum), given by, for R → 1 
>   hΔc = ¯ hc(1−R)/n<sub>c</sub>Leff

near the bottom it says

> the cavity mode has ﬁnite width Δc

my question: what is the "cavity mode width"? just the length of the cavity? a mode is just a given fundamental frequency.

Comment: Please read your posts after making them. There have been consistent typos in the math, probably because of how copy/paste works from whatever source you're using. You can use the "edit" button to fix these errors.

Comment: Please also read the [help page on mathjax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cavities (or resonators in general) have 'resonance' frequencies, which is what you are describing as the fundamental frequency (although of course there can be multiple resonance frequencies, such as different harmonics). However, the resonance frequency is only perfectly well-defined if there is no loss mechanism from the cavity. In practice, every cavity has a loss mechanism. This loss mechanism leads to an effective 'broadening' of the resonance condition.

A standard way to characterize this is by the response of the cavity to a drive field at a given frequency. The response function is not a Dirac delta at the resonance, but instead usually a Lorentzian with some finite width centered on the resonance. The width of this Lorentzian response function is often referred to as the cavity mode width.